# How do I get Key Ring Reward Cards to store other kinds of barcode?

Tags: barcode

I've started using [Key Ring Reward Cards](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.froogloid.kring.google.zxing.client.android&feature=search_result) to store my barcodes on my DroidX. I managed to scan in a couple of cards (Safeways and REI) but it refuses to scan any of my library cards and some other cards like Toys R Us.

Does anybody have any tips or tricks to getting all barcodes on these types of cards recognized?

Comment: Um, aren't you kind of asking "How can I get this app to do something it doesn't do?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they explicitly support a few hundred ([650](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.froogloid.kring.google.zxing.client.android&feature=search_result), as of this reading) rewards programs. So they don't support just every last bar code you might want to store, unfortunately.

That said, they do show a Toys R Us reward card in their banner graphic so you'd think it ought to upload that one. My guess is that you should nudge them about the reward cards you haven't been able to scan: http://www.keyringapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

I played with that app for a few days and if I recall correctly there's an option to manually enter the numbers printed below every barcode or some other unique identifier for the cards you want to use but won't scan.

Comment: I tried entering the barcode manually but it rejected it with an error message something like: "barcodes must be 9 or 10 digits"

Comment: Were you able to specify that it wasn't a barcode?  Like was there an option to tell it you were entering a user ID or something?  I seem to remember something like that.